# query for self join with grouping

Tags: sql, group-by, hsqldb, self-join

Given a set of course bookings I need to determine the total numbers and type of rooms required for students attending each courses. Courses can run parallel or nested or over-lapped. 

The logic to be achieved: for each course duration, locate all other courses active during that duration, and the sum of Number_of_students 
of those courses grouped on room_type.

Further complications exist, but a simplified version of the problem is presented below. 

I use hsqldb currently, the solution should use std sql syntax to be portable across databases.

Bookings table

```
BOOKING_ID| COURSE_ID| NUMBER_OF_STUDENTS| ROOM_TYPE_ID
    10    |    2     |        1          |    1
    20    |    1     |        2          |    1
    30    |    3     |        1          |    3
    40    |    1     |        3          |    4
    50    |    5     |        1          |    2
    60    |    6     |        2          |    2
    70    |    3     |        2          |    1
    80    |    4     |        1          |    3
```

Courses table

```
COURSE_ID| START_DATE |  END_DATE
    1    | 2018-05-15 |  2018-06-14    //sample course
    2    | 2018-05-11 |  2018-05-20    //starts before ends between sample course
    3    | 2018-05-18 |  2018-05-22    //starts between ends between sample course
    4    | 2018-05-20 |  2018-06-20    //starts between ends after sample course
    5    | 2018-05-10 |  2018-06-20    //starts before ends after sample course
    6    | 2018-05-10 |  2018-05-14    //starts and ends before sample course
    7    | 2018-06-15 |  2018-06-20    //starts and ends after sample course
```

Rooms Table (we do'nt really need this here, just for completeness)

```
ROOM_TYPE_ID| ROOM_CAPACITY| ROOM_LOCATION
    1       |    1         |  HILL
    2       |    2         |  HILL
    3       |    1         |  OCEAN
    4       |    2         |  OCEAN
```

the output (shown only for course_id 1, required for all courses)

```
COURSE_ID | ROOMTYPE | COURSE_STUDENT | OTHER_STUDENTS 
    1     |   1      |        2       |      3           //1(course 2) + 2 (course 3)
    1     |   2      |        0       |      1           //1(course 5)
    1     |   3      |        0       |      2           //1(course 3) + 1(course 4)
    1     |   4      |        3       |      0           //no students on others
```

I could ONLY figure out the condition for matching overlapped courses for a given course **startDate** , **endDate**

```
Courses.START_DATE <= startDate  AND Courses.END_DATE >= endDate    OR        //matches any course spanning current course
Courses.START_DATE >= startDate  AND Courses.END_DATE <= startDate  OR        //matches any course starting during the current course
Courses.START_DATE >= endDate    AND Courses.END_DATE <= endDate              //matches any course ending during the current course
```

beyond which my meager sql skills, fail me miserably. I could spin some java code to solve this....but that would be lame && inefficient.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to Fredt for pointing me in the correct direction... 
to join the main table with itself all records to all records and then filter based on overlapping course dates criteria.

The query below is inefficient but does the job for now....there could be more optimizations, i would like to hear other opinion

```
SELECT
        THIS_COURSE.COURSE_ID, 
        OTHER_COURSE.ROOM_TYPE_ID,
        SUM(CASE  WHEN THIS_COURSE.BOOKING_ID = OTHER_COURSE.BOOKING_ID THEN OTHER_COURSE.NUMBER_OF_STUDENTS ELSE 0 END) AS COURSE_STUDENTS,
        SUM(CASE  WHEN THIS_COURSE.BOOKING_ID <> OTHER_COURSE.BOOKING_ID THEN OTHER_COURSE.NUMBER_OF_STUDENTS ELSE 0 END) AS OTHER_STUDENTS,
        SUM(OTHER_COURSE.NUMBER_OF_STUDENTS) AS TOTAL_STUDENTS
FROM

(
    SELECT 
        BOOKINGS.BOOKING_ID, 
        BOOKINGS.COURSE_ID, 
        BOOKINGS.NUMBER_OF_STUDENTS, 
        BOOKINGS.ROOM_TYPE_ID, 
        COURSES.START_DATE, 
        COURSES.END_DATE 
    FROM 
        BOOKINGS , COURSES 
    WHERE 
        BOOKINGS.COURSE_ID = COURSES.COURSE_ID
) THIS_COURSE

LEFT JOIN 
(
    SELECT 
        BOOKINGS.BOOKING_ID, 
        BOOKINGS.COURSE_ID, 
        BOOKINGS.NUMBER_OF_STUDENTS, 
        BOOKINGS.ROOM_TYPE_ID, 
        COURSES.START_DATE, 
        COURSES.END_DATE 
    FROM 
        BOOKINGS , COURSES 
    WHERE 
        BOOKINGS.COURSE_ID = COURSES.COURSE_ID
) OTHER_COURSE

ON 
    THIS_COURSE.BOOKING_ID <> OTHER_COURSE.BOOKING_ID OR
    THIS_COURSE.BOOKING_ID = OTHER_COURSE.BOOKING_ID

WHERE
        (THIS_COURSE.START_DATE <= OTHER_COURSE.START_DATE AND THIS_COURSE.END_DATE >= OTHER_COURSE.END_DATE)  OR
        (THIS_COURSE.START_DATE <= OTHER_COURSE.START_DATE AND THIS_COURSE.END_DATE >= OTHER_COURSE.START_DATE)  OR
        (THIS_COURSE.START_DATE <= OTHER_COURSE.END_DATE   AND THIS_COURSE.END_DATE >= OTHER_COURSE.END_DATE)  

GROUP BY 
    THIS_COURSE.COURSE_ID, OTHER_COURSE.ROOM_TYPE_ID
```

Below is the sql to create the sample data

```
CREATE TABLE Bookings(BOOKING_ID INTEGER NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY, COURSE_ID INTEGER NOT NULL, NUMBER_OF_STUDENTS INTEGER NOT NULL, ROOM_TYPE_ID INTEGER NOT NULL)
CREATE TABLE Courses(COURSE_ID INTEGER NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY, START_DATE DATE,  END_DATE  DATE)
CREATE TABLE Rooms(ROOM_TYPE_ID INTEGER NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY, ROOM_CAPACITY INTEGER NOT NULL, ROOM_LOCATION VARCHAR(25))

INSERT INTO Bookings VALUES(    10   ,    2    ,        1         ,    1 )
INSERT INTO Bookings VALUES(    20   ,    1    ,        2         ,    1 )
INSERT INTO Bookings VALUES(    30   ,    3    ,        1         ,    3 )
INSERT INTO Bookings VALUES(    40   ,    1    ,        3         ,    4 )
INSERT INTO Bookings VALUES(    50   ,    5    ,        1         ,    2 )
INSERT INTO Bookings VALUES(    60   ,    6    ,        2         ,    2 )
INSERT INTO Bookings VALUES(    70   ,    3    ,        2         ,    1 )
INSERT INTO Bookings VALUES(    80   ,    4    ,        1         ,    3 )
INSERT INTO Bookings VALUES(    90   ,    7    ,        1         ,    4 )


INSERT INTO Courses VALUES(    1    ,'2018-05-15', '2018-06-14' )
INSERT INTO Courses VALUES(    2    ,'2018-05-11', '2018-05-20' )
INSERT INTO Courses VALUES(    3    ,'2018-05-18', '2018-05-22' )
INSERT INTO Courses VALUES(    4    ,'2018-05-20', '2018-06-20' )
INSERT INTO Courses VALUES(    5    ,'2018-05-10', '2018-06-20' )
INSERT INTO Courses VALUES(    6    ,'2018-05-10', '2018-05-14' )
INSERT INTO Courses VALUES(    7    ,'2018-06-15', '2018-06-20' )


INSERT INTO Rooms VALUES(    1       ,    1        ,  'HILL')
INSERT INTO Rooms VALUES(    2       ,    2        ,  'HILL')
INSERT INTO Rooms VALUES(    3       ,    1        ,  'OCEAN')
INSERT INTO Rooms VALUES(    4       ,    2        ,  'OCEAN')
```

Comment: The query looks good. You can use the WITH clause to factor out the repeated inner query. You can also use the OVERLAPS predicate with the dates. For example `PERIOD THIS_COURSE.START_DATE, THIS_COURSE.END_DATE + 1 DAY) OVERLAPS PERIOD (OTHER_COURSE_START_DATE, OTHER_COURSE_END_DATE + 1 DAY)`. Note the end periods are exclusive so you need to add 1 DAY

Comment: Thanks fredt, I will try to incorporate the OVERLAPS predicate, however i could not get my head around your suggestion of WITH clause to remove THIS_COURSE and OTHER_COURSE block, could you elaborate further.

Comment: I re-wrote the query using your example data

Answer (score 0):

You actually want the required number of rooms of each type of room for each course. therefore you need to start with the COURSES table and join it with the two other tables.

```
SELECT * FROM COURSES JOIN BOOKINGS USING (COURSE_ID) JOIN ROOMS USING (ROOM_TYPE_ID)
```

This gives you a long list of all room bookings. You can then treat this table as a sub-query table and joint it to itself based on the date periods.

```
WITH ROOM_BOOKINGS AS (
  SELECT 
    BOOKINGS.BOOKING_ID, 
    BOOKINGS.COURSE_ID, 
    BOOKINGS.NUMBER_OF_STUDENTS, 
    BOOKINGS.ROOM_TYPE_ID, 
    COURSES.START_DATE, 
    COURSES.END_DATE, 
    ROOMS.ROOM_CAPACITY
  FROM 
    COURSES JOIN BOOKINGS USING (COURSE_ID) JOIN ROOMS USING (ROOM_TYPE_ID)
 ) 
 SELECT * FROM ROOM_BOOKINGS THIS_COURSE LEFT JOIN ROOM_BOOKINGS OTHER_COURSE
 ON (THIS_COURSE.START_DATE, THIS_COURSE.END_DATE + 1 DAY) OVERLAPS (OTHER_COURSE.START_DATE, OTHER_COURSE.END_DATE + 1 DAY)
 AND THIS_COURSE.ROOM_TYPE_ID = OTHER_COURSE.ROOM_TYPE_ID 
 AND THIS_COURSE.COURSE_ID  <> OTHER_COURSE.COURSE_ID
```

You need to complete the above query and add a condition to the SELECT to return only one course. You also need a GROUP BY A.COURSE_ID, A.ROOM_TYPE_ID, A.NUMBER_OF_STUDENTS, ... and SUM(B.NUMBER_OF_STUDENS) to achieve the desired output.

As you can see, it is not a trivial tasks to write an advanced level SQL query and it requires a good knowledge of the SQL language.